# How to get date in the yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSZ in Oracle 11g toad database point

Tags: python, database, oracle, date, toad

How to get date in the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSZ` in Oracle 11g toad database point. In other words i want to fetch datetime in ISO8601 format in Oracle 11g. I want the today's datetime in the below mentioned format,one of the sample data,

```
As I am new to oracle i am not sure how to proceed with this,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, I have found answer for my question,

'''
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:mi:ss.ff."oz"') AS iodt from dual;
'''

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP` function

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('2020-01-18 19:56:30.123456', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
  FROM DUAL;
```

If the timestamp is a constant known at compile time, a literal would be even better:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-01-18 19:56:30.123456'
  FROM DUAL;
```

---

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm